# How to use Mathematica to help me get highest score in every layout?

Tags: programming, game

The game is hitting the headline in these day and everyone can click [this link](http://www.yuxidz.cn/yx/yx.php?oid=tspcogui) to play it.The game have a very simple rule like following:

**Game Rule**

- **It will give you a initial layout when you click "重新开始".**

[image]

Every layout have five color.

- **When you click a rectangle adjoining(Up,Down,Left,Right) other $n$ rectangles each other
  except $n$ equal to 1,you will get $n*n$ scores,and these rectangles
  will eliminate simultaneously.**

Such as you have a this initial layout

[image]

You click this rectangle arrow to point out

[image]

You'll get $5*5$ scores and eliminate these rectangle

[image]$\rightarrow$
[image]

Or another exmaple

[image]
$\rightarrow$
[image]
$\rightarrow$
[image]
$\rightarrow$
[image]

- **If a inteval between the columns appear,the right columns will move
  to left to patch it.**

So how to use `Mathematica` to guide us to get highest score in every initial layout?

Comment: @Kuba Red+Blue?No they cannot be added.Just a same color and they adjoining each other.Then you can get score.

Comment: What's reason to downvote?Can you give a reason,please?

Comment: You need to tell us more about the game. For instance, how are numbers mapped to colors?

Comment: There is no down-vote.

Comment: @m_goldberg Confuse me.Or do you have not seem that link?

Comment: I do not follow links to sites I don't know and trust. Question should be self-contained.

Comment: @m_goldberg It surprised me.Have a such rule we cannot give a Chinese link but a American link in SE?Anyway I will give a specific directions for these game.

Comment: There are at least two questions here, both fairly complicated. One is about how to program the game and the other is about how to program a strategy for the game. Clearly the first must be answered *before* the second can be attempted. How about if you do the first part -- then others might be more interested in attempting the second.

Comment: @bills Ok.Give me some minutes.I'll try to do the first part.But I cannot sure I can achieve it.

Comment: @yode are you really looking for an algorithm other than trying all possible moves(perhaps with some pruning)?

Comment: Yode, it seems to me that this is far too complicated a project for this format. As bill said, your question requires tons of work on the part of the responder. This is NOT just about implementing an existing strategy in *Mathematica*, but really about FINDING such a strategy first. Unless you can propose an algorithmic approach to be implemented and a test system on which to test it (e.g. a Mathematica implementation of that game), I don't think this is an appropriate question, and I am voting to close it.